# Show image when option is selected

Tags: javascript, image, select

I would like to make a select that when you click an option, an image will show next to the form. Nothing from this needs to be sent to the database, it's just for looks.

I’ve tried searching online but I am only able to find images in the select options, which is not what I’m looking for. I’m also not sure what it should be done with, most likely Javascript. But whatever works would be fine.

Example code (form):

```
<form>
<select name="optionType">
    <option value="" hidden selected> </option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select><br>
<input type="submit" name="optionAdd" value="submit"><br>
```

Example outcome picture:
[image: 1]

Mind you I am not looking for it to show after the submit is clicked but simply when the option is selected. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: One option is indeed to use Javascript. You can listen to the option change event and then show the image.

Comment: I see yeah, the onchange Event might definitely help. Thanks for the tip but I'm unsure how to make it work with an image however as i'm not that experienced wtih Javascript.

Comment: You would have to define an event listener and then show the image you want to show using code in your event handler. Some javascript knowledge is needed for this.

Comment: try my answer posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

HTML

```
<select name="optionType" onchange="renderImage()" id="selectOption">
    <option value="" hidden selected> </option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<img id="myImg" src="compman.gif" width="107" height="98">
```

JS

```
function renderImage() {
var selected = document.getElementById("selectOption");
var imgUrl = "";
if (selected.value == 1) {
    imgUrl = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494253109108-2e30c049369b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80";
} else if (selected.value == 2) {
    imgUrl = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80";
} else {
    imgUrl = "";
}

document.getElementById("myImg").src = imgUrl;
```

}

Try this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kamyh1tq/): https://jsfiddle.net/kamyh1tq/

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i'm looking for!
One more thing though, is it possible to hide the placeholder if there's no image shown?

Comment: Thanks again, exactly what i wanted!